# MySQL fulltext search isn't matching as expected

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a pretty simple query that doesn't seem to be giving me the results I'd like.  I'm trying to allow the user to search for a resturant by its name, address, or city using a fulltext search.

here is my query:

```
SELECT ESTAB_NAME, ESTAB_ADDRESS, ESTAB_CITY
FROM restaurant_restaurants rr
WHERE 
  MATCH (rr.ESTAB_NAME, rr.ESTAB_ADDRESS, rr.ESTAB_CITY) 
  AGAINST ('*new* *hua*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
LIMIT 0, 500
```

New Hua is the restaurant that exists within the table.  However when i do a search for '*ting* *ho*' i get the results I would expect.

Does anyone have any idea what What is going on?
I'm using a MyISAM storage engine on MySQL version 5.0.41

Comment: You mean MyISAM, not MyISMAP.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, the full-text index settings have set a minimum word length of 4 - I believe this is the default. You'll need to change these settings, even for BOOLEAN MODE (as per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html). Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html for the settings to change.

Answer (score 1):

I think Michael is right, but also, you probably want to remove the ***** characters unless that's actually in the title you're searching for. MATCH AGAINST doesn't require a "match all" type of parameter.

Comment: He's using Boolean Mode, so the * acts like a wildcard for any sequence of characters. However, that might be a good idea not to use them anyway, since that's usually not the kind of behavior you'd expect while searching (at least, I wouldn't...)

Answer (score 0):

My guess: "new" is a [Mysql Default Stop Word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html). See Michael Madsen's second link to see how to change the stop word list and regain the restaurant.

Comment: Boolean mode should not behave like that when using the wildcard, accoring to the documentation, and even if it did, there should be a match due to Hua.